# Highcharts series name formatting on export

Tags: highcharts, legend, font-size, series

How do we exactly change the Font size, of the series name on exporting, as pdf, images?

The image below has the names "Series 1 name." and "Series 2 name.", I want that to have a different formatting.

Sample chart image.
[image: i]

Comment: almost similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30050839/highcharts-how-do-i-change-the-legend-location-in-the-export-of-a-chart), however check this example http://jsfiddle.net/w8z1uq9s/

Comment: There're two sets of series names in your chart: first on the plot and second in the legend. Which one do you want to change?

Comment: I want to format both.